# Vscode LiveServer opens with an ERROR on browser

Tags: visual-studio-code, port, liveserver

My LiveServer extension was working perfectly when i worked with HTML,CSS and JS. But after spending some time learning flutter and dart, I tried to go back with HTML for a web project... But my liveserver is not working as before...

This is the error i got when i start the live server

"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)"

I have already tried google this for an answer but unfortunately i coudn't found any...